# Offline installation of CUDA runtime package

Tags: apt, nvidia, cuda, offline

I am attempting to install the CUDA runtime package on a machine with no access to the internet.

Current method:

```
curl -o /tmp/cuda_key.pub 
http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
apt-key add /tmp/cuda_key.pub
curl -o /tmp/cuda/cuda_install.deb "https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb"
dpkg -i /tmp/cuda/cuda_install.deb
apt-get update && apt-get --download-only install -y --allow-unauthenticated cuda-runtime-9-2=9.2.148*
```

When I try install this on a different machine by running the following command it fails:

```
dpkg -i *.deb
```

This method works only when I have access to the internet to fix the broken packages via

```
apt install -f
```

Is there a method currently to install cuda-runtime-9-2=9.2.148* completely offline?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation of CUDA 9.2](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/9.2/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#ubuntu-installation) it should be possible. Please also take care about your Ubuntu version. CUDA 9.2 supports Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.10. If you want to use Ubuntu 18.04 then use CUDA 10.

Install repository meta-data

```
$ sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-<distro>_<version>_<architecture>.deb
```

Installing the CUDA public GPG key

When installing using the local repo:

```
$ sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-<version>/7fa2af80.pub
```

Update the Apt repository cache

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Install CUDA

```
$ sudo apt-get install cuda
```

Please check also the pre and post installation steps in documentation!

Comment: I ended up downloading the package inside a docker container with the exact same OS/kernel version. It finally works, thanks.